# Splitting game screen into right and left touch?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

So I am new to Swift and I am trying to figure out how to split the screen basically in half and make it so that if the right side of the screen is tapped then the object will move over to the right and if the left side of the screen is tapped then the object will move over to the left. I have tried to play around with the gestures but I haven't gotten very far. How can I fix this? It gives me an error at `locationinNode`

I am using storyboard to add the moving object.

This is what I have:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

@IBOutlet var Lane: [UIImageView]!
@IBOutlet weak var Player: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Platform: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func MoveLeft(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.Player.center = CGPoint(x: self.Player.center.x - 125, y: self.Player.center.y)
        }, completion: nil)
}

func MoveRight(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.Player.center = CGPoint(x: self.Player.center.x + 125, y: self.Player.center.y)
        }, completion: nil)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
 let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
 if location.x < self.size.width/2 {
// left code
MoveLeft()
 }
 else {
  // right code
 }

}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the `touch` in the `touchesBegan`? I think you should use the `touches.first as! UITouch` like so:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let location = (touches.first as! UITouch).locationInView(self.view)
    if location.x < self.view.bounds.size.width/2 { 
        // left code
        MoveLeft()
    } else {
        // right code
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so I replaced it but it is giving me the error: "Cannot invoke 'locationInView' with an argument list of type '(ViewController)'

Comment: Instead of using `self` with `self.view`

Comment: You're the best! Thank you so much @Bannings if I can ask you one more question. If I wanted to restrict the object from going outside the screen how would I do that?

Comment: See `CGRectContainsPoint()`